# Google Colab slow. 2.5 hours/epoch running EfficientNetB0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Running EfficientNetB0 + some layers is extremely slow.
I upgraded to Google Colab Pro and that cut the training time down to 2.5 hours/epoch...

Its 68 million trainable parameters but it still shouldnt be this slow.

I am storing the files locally on google colab, not in google drive, so that is not the problem.

```py
train_folder = "/content/train/train"
test_folder = "/content/test/test"
```

This, i think, tells me that i have the gpu available.

```
gpu_info = '\n'.join(gpu_info)
if gpu_info.find('failed') >= 0:
  print('Select the Runtime → "Change runtime type" menu to enable a GPU accelerator, ')
  print('and then re-execute this cell.')
else:
  print(gpu_info)
```

```py
Sun Dec  6 04:29:55 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.45.01    Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   44C    P0    26W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                 ERR! |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```py
from psutil import virtual_memory
ram_gb = virtual_memory().total / 1e9
print('Your runtime has {:.1f} gigabytes of available RAM\n'.format(ram_gb))

if ram_gb < 20:

  print('To enable a high-RAM runtime, select the Runtime → "Change runtime type"')

  print('menu, and then select High-RAM in the Runtime shape dropdown. Then, ')

  print('re-execute this cell.')
else:
  print('You are using a high-RAM runtime!')
```

```
Your runtime has 27.4 gigabytes of available RAM

You are using a high-RAM runtime!
```

I am training on 60.000 images and 16.000 in the validation set.

Here is some code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout, PReLU, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import applications

from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from glob import glob

num_classes = 423
epochs = 20
batch_size = 96
img_height = 224
img_width = 224
IMAGE_SIZE = [img_height, img_width]

base_model = keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape= IMAGE_SIZE + [3])

x = Flatten()(base_model.output)
x = Dense(1024)(x)
x = PReLU()(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
#x = Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)

output = Dense(num_classes, activation= 'softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = output)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(
  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer=opt,
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define your data generator
_train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,
        rotation_range=180,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.3,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode='reflect',
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)


_val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)


train_generator = _train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = train_info, 
directory = train_folder, x_col = "filename", 
y_col = "artist", seed = 42,
batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True, 
class_mode="sparse", target_size = IMAGE_SIZE)

valid_generator = _val_generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = test_info, 
directory = test_folder, x_col = "filename", 
y_col = "artist", seed = 42,
batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True, 
class_mode="sparse", target_size = IMAGE_SIZE)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1,
                              patience=2, min_lr=0)

r = model.fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  validation_data=valid_generator,
  epochs=epochs,
  steps_per_epoch=len_train // batch_size,
  validation_steps=len_test // batch_size,
  callbacks=[reduce_lr]
)
```

Anyone know how to speed it up?

edit:
model.summary()

(had to cut of many layers because it didnt fit in the body)

("Body is limited to 30000 characters")

```py
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
_______________________________________________________________________________
block6c_expand_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 1152)   4608        block6c_expand_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_expand_activation (Acti (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block6c_expand_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_dwconv (DepthwiseConv2D (None, 7, 7, 1152)   28800       block6c_expand_activation[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_bn (BatchNormalization) (None, 7, 7, 1152)   4608        block6c_dwconv[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_activation (Activation) (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block6c_bn[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_se_squeeze (GlobalAvera (None, 1152)         0           block6c_activation[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_se_reshape (Reshape)    (None, 1, 1, 1152)   0           block6c_se_squeeze[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_se_reduce (Conv2D)      (None, 1, 1, 48)     55344       block6c_se_reshape[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_se_expand (Conv2D)      (None, 1, 1, 1152)   56448       block6c_se_reduce[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_se_excite (Multiply)    (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block6c_activation[0][0]         
                                                                 block6c_se_expand[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_project_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 7, 7, 192)    221184      block6c_se_excite[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_project_bn (BatchNormal (None, 7, 7, 192)    768         block6c_project_conv[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_drop (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7, 192)    0           block6c_project_bn[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6c_add (Add)               (None, 7, 7, 192)    0           block6c_drop[0][0]               
                                                                 block6b_add[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_expand_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 7, 7, 1152)   221184      block6c_add[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_expand_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 1152)   4608        block6d_expand_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_expand_activation (Acti (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block6d_expand_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_dwconv (DepthwiseConv2D (None, 7, 7, 1152)   28800       block6d_expand_activation[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_bn (BatchNormalization) (None, 7, 7, 1152)   4608        block6d_dwconv[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_activation (Activation) (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block6d_bn[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_se_squeeze (GlobalAvera (None, 1152)         0           block6d_activation[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_se_reshape (Reshape)    (None, 1, 1, 1152)   0           block6d_se_squeeze[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_se_reduce (Conv2D)      (None, 1, 1, 48)     55344       block6d_se_reshape[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_se_expand (Conv2D)      (None, 1, 1, 1152)   56448       block6d_se_reduce[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_se_excite (Multiply)    (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block6d_activation[0][0]         
                                                                 block6d_se_expand[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_project_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 7, 7, 192)    221184      block6d_se_excite[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_project_bn (BatchNormal (None, 7, 7, 192)    768         block6d_project_conv[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_drop (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7, 192)    0           block6d_project_bn[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6d_add (Add)               (None, 7, 7, 192)    0           block6d_drop[0][0]               
                                                                 block6c_add[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_expand_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 7, 7, 1152)   221184      block6d_add[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_expand_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 1152)   4608        block7a_expand_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_expand_activation (Acti (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block7a_expand_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_dwconv (DepthwiseConv2D (None, 7, 7, 1152)   10368       block7a_expand_activation[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_bn (BatchNormalization) (None, 7, 7, 1152)   4608        block7a_dwconv[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_activation (Activation) (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block7a_bn[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_se_squeeze (GlobalAvera (None, 1152)         0           block7a_activation[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_se_reshape (Reshape)    (None, 1, 1, 1152)   0           block7a_se_squeeze[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_se_reduce (Conv2D)      (None, 1, 1, 48)     55344       block7a_se_reshape[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_se_expand (Conv2D)      (None, 1, 1, 1152)   56448       block7a_se_reduce[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_se_excite (Multiply)    (None, 7, 7, 1152)   0           block7a_activation[0][0]         
                                                                 block7a_se_expand[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_project_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 7, 7, 320)    368640      block7a_se_excite[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7a_project_bn (BatchNormal (None, 7, 7, 320)    1280        block7a_project_conv[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
top_conv (Conv2D)               (None, 7, 7, 1280)   409600      block7a_project_bn[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
top_bn (BatchNormalization)     (None, 7, 7, 1280)   5120        top_conv[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
top_activation (Activation)     (None, 7, 7, 1280)   0           top_bn[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 62720)        0           top_activation[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1024)         64226304    flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu (PReLU)                 (None, 1024)         1024        dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 1024)         4096        p_re_lu[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 423)          433575      batch_normalization[0][0]        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 68,714,570
Trainable params: 68,670,499
Non-trainable params: 44,071
```

OK, so 64 million of the parameters are from my own dense layer.
But i have trained before with well over hundred million parameters and it was not this slow even on standard Google Colab.

Yesterday i ran vgg16 + some layers.
But at that time 138 million of the parameters came from vgg16.
Maybe training is optimized for these models and it is slowing down now because of this architecture where my own second to last dense layer holds almost all parameters?

edit: Removing that layer did not help much. Just keeping the final output layer it is still around 2.5 hours/epoch. Now 30 million parameters in total.

edit2:
I just remembered i trained a resnet50 a few days ago with these added final layers and parameters:

```py
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1024)         102761472   flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu (PReLU)                 (None, 1024)         1024        dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 1024)         4096        p_re_lu[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 423)          433575      batch_normalization[0][0]        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 126,787,879
Trainable params: 126,732,711
Non-trainable params: 55,168
```

Average time per epoch was `883s`.

Maybe i have reached some user limit and it doesnt matter that i purchased Google Colab Pro today?

Comment: Please add `model.summary()`. I am not familiar with EfficientNetB0. Why do you think it is slow ?

Comment: Hi, i made an edit with model.summary() and more.

Comment: Have you tried resnet with the same 76000 images ?

Comment: @Andrey Yes, everything is the same except that i changed to EfficientNetB0.